# zabbix not sending email to gmail

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, zabbix

I have been busy trying this for hours now. 
What am I missing here? Does anybody have any clues?

I am trying to send notifications emails with zabbix to gmail. 
Have set up the email account as follow.

```
Type: 'Email'
SMTP Server: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP server Port: '25'
SMTP HELO: 'gmail.com'
SMTP email: '[username]@gmail.com'
Connection security 'none'
Authentication: 'username and password'
Username '[username]' // without @gmail.com
Password '[password]'
Enabled 'checked'
```

I have also created an action and a trigger. 
This works perfect.

If I look at reports and audits I see the following;

```
    07/30/2018 04:44:31 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Media type  Updated 0       Media type [Email]
07/30/2018 04:43:28 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Action  Updated 0       Name: Asterisk Communication
07/30/2018 04:40:56 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Action  Updated 0       Name: Asterisk Communication
07/30/2018 04:40:32 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Action  Updated 0       Name: Asterisk Communication
07/30/2018 04:40:01 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Action  Updated 0       Name: Asterisk Communication
07/30/2018 04:39:46 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Action  Updated 0       Name: Asterisk Communication
07/30/2018 04:30:38 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Media type  Updated 0       Media type [Email]
07/30/2018 04:15:10 PM  wesley  111.108.30.208  Media type  Updated 0       Media type [Email]
```

It seems to me that the function is working like it should, but I don't receive any emails. Am I doing something wrong here?

I also set the non-secure apps options on in Gmail and I have opened port 25 on the server.

Help is highly appreciated.
As always Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: see this image for reference]

Use 587 port instead of 25

smpt.gmail.com uses port 587 or 465

And verify whether the password of the mail account is correct or not. if it fails it will not send emails.

check with this link for more options

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

For SSL

```
Type: 'Email'
SMTP Server: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP server Port: '465'
SMTP HELO: 'gmail.com'
SMTP email: 'username@gmail.com'
Connection security 'SSL/TLS'
Authentication: 'username and password'
Username 'user@gmaillcom' 
Password '<yourPassword>'
Enabled 'checked'
```

For TLS

```
Type: 'Email'
SMTP Server: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP server Port: '587'
SMTP HELO: 'gmail.com'
SMTP email: 'username@gmail.com'
Connection security 'STARTTLS'
Authentication: 'username and password'
Username 'user@gmaillcom' 
Password '<yourPassword>'
Enabled 'checked'
```